# controlling lights and fans through relays connected to arduino and ethernet shield, but html page stops loading

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I connected my lights and fans to a eight channel relay board which is connected to my arduino and ethernet shield.

The html page loads fine and all the relays work, but after a few hours the html page stops loading until I press reset.

Here's the code, would really appreciate some help.

Check the attachment for the source code

```
/*Induino R3 User Guide - Program 18.2 - A Simple Webserver that Controls using Links
Modified original Webserver Example

A simple web server that shows the value of the analog input pins.
using an Arduino Wiznet Ethernet shield. 

Circuit:
* Ethernet shield attached to pins 10, 11, 12, 13
* Analog inputs attached to pins A0 through A5 (optional)

created 18 Dec 2009
by David A. Mellis
modified 9 Apr 2012
by Tom Igoe

*/

#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Enter a MAC address and IP address for your controller below.
// The IP address will be dependent on your local network:
byte mac[] = { 
0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress ip(192,168,1,177);

// Initialize the Ethernet server library
// with the IP address and port you want to use 
// (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetServer server(80); 
String req; // a variable to store the GET request

boolean state = 0; // a variable to store the state of the LED 
boolean state1 = 0;
boolean state2 = 0;
boolean state3 = 0;

boolean state4 = 0; // a variable to store the state of the LED 
boolean state5 = 0;
boolean state6 = 0;
boolean state7 = 0;




String state_val[]={"OFF","ON"}; // A Variable to store the State of the LED as String
String state_val1[]={"1OFF","1ON"};
String state_val2[]={"2OFF","2ON"};
String state_val3[]={"3OFF","3ON"};

String state_val4[]={"4OFF","4ON"}; // A Variable to store the State of the LED as String
String state_val6[]={"6OFF","6ON"};
String state_val7[]={"7OFF","7ON"};



void setup() {
// Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
Serial.begin(9600);
while (!Serial) {
; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
}


// start the Ethernet connection and the server:
Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
server.begin();
Serial.print("server is at ");
Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
pinMode(5,OUTPUT); // RGB LED RED is on Pin 6
pinMode(6,OUTPUT);
pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
pinMode(8,OUTPUT);

pinMode(2,OUTPUT); // RGB LED RED is on Pin 6
pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
pinMode(14,OUTPUT);

}


void loop() {
// listen for incoming clients
EthernetClient client = server.available();
if (client) { // Check if there is a client available
Serial.println("new client");
while (client.connected()) {                    // check if the client is connected
  if (client.available()) {                    // Check if there is a request from the client

    Serial.print("$$$$");
    req="";                                    // reset the request variable
    while(client.available())                 // Read data from the client 1 byte at a time as                    long as there is data
    {  
    char c=client.read();                    // Read 1 byte of data from the client
    if(c==13) // Check if the data read is a Carriage Return a.ka. Enter, This means end of first line - the line starting with GET and ending with HTTP/1.1
      break; // Since we have read the first line, we need not read the remaining data for storage, so exit the while loop
    req += c; // append the read data to the existing value
    delayMicroseconds(1000);
    }
    // if the while loop above exited from the break statement, then there is data in the client buffer, which needs to be read to be removed
    // we need to read this data to empty the buffer
    while(client.available())                 // While loop to read the data to empty buffer
    {
      client.read();
      delayMicroseconds(1000);
    }
    Serial.println(req);                     // print the value of the request to the Serial Monitor for debugging
    Serial.println("XXX");
  }
      if(find_string(req,"GET /?ON"))       // Check if the received Request containts the String ON
      {
        state = 1;                          // Set the State Variable
        digitalWrite(5,state);              // Set the state to the RED LED
      }
      if(find_string(req,"GET /?OFF"))      // Check if the received Request containts the String ON
      {
        state = 0;                          // Set the State Variable
        digitalWrite(5,state);            
      }
      if(find_string(req,"GET /?1ON"))       // Check if the received Request containts the String ON
      {
        state1 = 1;                          // Set the State Variable
        digitalWrite(6,state1);              // Set the state to the RED LED
      }
      if(find_string(req,"GET /?1OFF"))      // Check if the received Request containts the String ON
      {
        state1 = 0;                          // Set the State Variable
        digitalWrite(6,state1);            
      }
      if(find_string(req,"GET /?2ON"))       // Check if the received Request containts the String ON
      {
        state2 = 1;                          // Set the State Variable
        digitalWrite(7,state2);              // Set the state to the RED LED
      }
      if(find_string(req,"GET /?2OFF"))      // Check if the received Request containts the String ON
      {
        state2 = 0;                          // Set the State Variable
        digitalWrite(7,state2);            
      }
      if(find_string(req,"GET /?3ON"))       // Check if the received Request containts the String ON
      {
        state3 = 1;                          // Set the State Variable
        digitalWrite(8,state3);              // Set the state to the RED LED
      }
      if(find_string(req,"GET /?3OFF"))      // Check if the received Request containts the String ON
      {
        state3 = 0;                          // Set the State Variable
        digitalWrite(8,state3);            
      } 



      if(find_string(req,"GET /?4ON"))       // Check if the received Request containts the String ON
      {
        state4 = 1;                          // Set the State Variable
        digitalWrite(2,state4);              // Set the state to the RED LED
      }
      if(find_string(req,"GET /?4OFF"))      // Check if the received Request containts the String ON
      {
        state4 = 0;                          // Set the State Variable
        digitalWrite(2,state4);            
      }
      if(find_string(req,"GET /?5ON"))       // Check if the received Request containts the String ON
      {
        state5 = 1;                          // Set the State Variable
        digitalWrite(3,state5);              // Set the state to the RED LED
      }
      if(find_string(req,"GET /?5OFF"))      // Check if the received Request containts the String ON
      {
        state5 = 0;                          // Set the State Variable
        digitalWrite(3,state5);            
      }
      if(find_string(req,"GET /?6ON"))       // Check if the received Request containts the String ON
      {
        state6 = 1;                          // Set the State Variable
        digitalWrite(9,state6);              // Set the state to the RED LED
      }
      if(find_string(req,"GET /?6OFF"))      // Check if the received Request containts the String ON
      {
        state6 = 0;                          // Set the State Variable
        digitalWrite(9,state6);            
      }
      if(find_string(req,"GET /?7ON"))       // Check if the received Request containts the String ON
      {
        state7 = 1;                          // Set the State Variable
        digitalWrite(14,state7);              // Set the state to the RED LED
      }
      if(find_string(req,"GET /?7OFF"))      // Check if the received Request containts the String ON
      {
        state7 = 0;                          // Set the State Variable
        digitalWrite(14,state7);            
      } 


 Serial.println("here 1");           // for debugging

 client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");    // start responding with the DATA to the client & Send out  the response header
 client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
 client.println("Connection: close");  // the connection will be closed after completion of the   responsedelay(1);
 client.println();
 client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");    // Start of the HTML Page
 client.println("<html>");                  
 client.println("<br />"); 
 delayMicroseconds(500);
      if(state)                             // Check the State and print the LINK on the Page accordingly
      {
        client.println("<a href= \"/?"+state_val[0]+" \">");
      }
      else
      {
        client.println("<a href= \"/?"+state_val[1]+" \">");
      }
      client.println("Click Here to Switch "+state_val[!state]+" -RED of RGB LED");
      client.println("</a>");
      client.println("<br />"); 
      delayMicroseconds(500);
      if(state1)                             // Check the State and print the LINK on the Page accordingly
      {
        client.println("<a href= \"/?"+state_val1[0]+" \">");
      }
      else
      {
        client.println("<a href= \"/?"+state_val1[1]+" \">");
      }
      client.println("Click Here to Switch "+state_val1[!state1]+" -RED of RGB LED");
      client.println("</a>");          
      client.println("<br />"); 
      delayMicroseconds(500);
      if(state2)                             // Check the State and print the LINK on the Page accordingly
      {
        client.println("<a href= \"/?"+state_val2[0]+" \">");
      }
      else
      }
        client.println("<a href= \"/?"+state_val2[1]+" \">");
      }
      client.println("Click Here to Switch "+state_val2[!state2]+" -RED of RGB LED");
      client.println("</a>"); 
       client.println("<br />"); 
      delayMicroseconds(500);
      if(state3)                             // Check the State and print the LINK on the Page accordingly
      {
        client.println("<a href= \"/?"+state_val3[0]+" \">");
      }
      else
      {
        client.println("<a href= \"/?"+state_val3[1]+" \">");
      }
      client.println("Click Here to Switch "+state_val3[!state3]+" -RED of RGB LED");
      client.println("</a>");  
      client.println("<br />"); 
      delayMicroseconds(500);
      if(state4)                             // Check the State and print the LINK on the Page accordingly
      {
        client.println("<a href= \"/?"+state_val4[0]+" \">");
      }
      else
      {
        client.println("<a href= \"/?"+state_val4[1]+" \">");
      }
      client.println("Click Here to Switch "+state_val4[!state4]+" -RED of RGB LED");
      client.println("</a>");
      client.println("<br />"); 
      delayMicroseconds(500);
      if(state5)                             // Check the State and print the LINK on the Page accordingly
      {
        client.println("<a href= \"/?"+state_val5[0]+" \">");
      }
      else
      {
        client.println("<a href= \"/?"+state_val5[1]+" \">");
      }
      client.println("Click Here to Switch "+state_val5[!state5]+" -RED of RGB LED");
      client.println("</a>");          
      client.println("<br />");
     delayMicroseconds(500);
      if(state6)                             // Check the State and print the LINK on the Page accordingly
      {
        client.println("<a href= \"/?"+state_val6[0]+" \">");
      }
      else
      {
        client.println("<a href= \"/?"+state_val6[1]+" \">");
      }
      client.println("Click Here to Switch "+state_val6[!state6]+" -RED of RGB LED");
      client.println("</a>"); 
       client.println("<br />"); 
     delayMicroseconds(500);
      if(state7)                             // Check the State and print the LINK on the Page accordingly
      {
        client.println("<a href= \"/?"+state_val7[0]+" \">");
      }
      else
      {
        client.println("<a href= \"/?"+state_val7[1]+" \">");
      }
      client.println("Click Here to Switch "+state_val7[!state7]+" -RED of RGB LED");
      client.println("</a>"); 


       client.println("</html>");
      break;
 }
  client.stop();
  Serial.println("client disonnected");

 }
 }
  // A Function to locate a given search string in a given base string
  boolean find_string(String base, String search)
 {
 int len = search.length(); // find the length of the base string
   for(int m = 0; m<((base.length()-len)+1);m++)// Iterate from the beginning of the base string till the end minus length of the substring
 { 

   if(base.substring(m,(m+len))==search) // Check if the extracted Substring Matches the Search   String
  {
    return true;        // if it matches exit the function with a true value
   }

 }
   return false; // if the above loop did not find any matches, control would come here and return a false value
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have pretty much the same thing working for me, I don't have a problem with locking up, but in my testing, I did notice that certain web browsers send quite a bit of information to the "web server" regarding the request.  I make my request a char[1024] and capped off char copying and char searching @ 1023 characters.

To troubleshoot the problem I would suggest looping a series of light requests at a given interval.  Then after experiencing the lock up and documenting the time, do it again with a more spread out interval.  You might be able to narrow this down this way.  Also, take the browser out of the equation by using netcat and sending exactly only the request that you are looking for.

Good Luck!